# Explanation for why John Kramer says he is responsible for Jeff's kid's death

Tags: saw-3

In Saw 3, during the end and the parallell Saw 4 movie, John told Jeff that the reason he could kill him was because he (John Kramer or Jigsaw) was the one responsible for his child's death. Is he referring to Jeff's son Dylan or that he would soon be responsible for his daughter's death?

It was the med student Timothy young who drove drunk into Dylan and Hoffman freed Jeff's daughter. What child does he mean? Was it because Jigsaw had another game and that game might have been to find the door Strahm found, shoot Strahm or wait for cops to find him and Jigsaw knew that wouldn't happen so he would never see her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He meant his daughter. Kramer had nothing to do with Dylan's death, but he's endangered the life of Jeff's daughter to test him. Notice that he's careful with his phrasing and says that Jeff will "finally come face to face with the man responsible for **the loss of your child**" and "the man accountable for **taking your child**", instead of saying "the death of your son". Kramer explains it in the tape in the end:

> *I* am the person responsible for the loss of your child. *I* am the only person who knows where your daughter is. She only has a limited supply of air, Jeff.